# Get response from Php Curl post

Tags: php, json, curl

I have a page called "posted.php". From which i am posting data to postjson.php. That is happening alright. But how to catch those posted data in postjson.php

The code of posted.php is as follows :

```
**$url = 'http://localhost/Sudips/json/postjson.php';

//Initiate cURL.
$ch = curl_init($url);

//The JSON data.
$data = array("name" => "Hagrid", "age" => "36");                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   

$ch = curl_init($url);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 
    'Content-Type:application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

$result = curl_exec($ch);**
```

I need to get these data posted in postjson.php. How to get them in postjson.php. I am trying to $_POST in postjson.php.but it shows nothing.

Comment: in postjson.php try `var_dump($_POST)` and in posted.php add `echo $result`

Comment: what does `var_dump($_POST)` give you in **postjson.php**? And can you add `if(curl_errno($ch)){echo curl_error($ch);}` to **posted.php**

Comment: in postjson.php it returns array(0) { }

Answer (score 1):

You are passing value as below curl request and then retrive value of variable, and then explode the | and then store in variable.

sudo /usr/bin/curl -o "mac_id=$partner|$password|$credit_point" http://www.example.com/credit_request_cloud.php

$mac_id=trim($_REQUEST['mac_id']);

$array =(explode("-",$mac_id));

$mac_id = $array[0];

$rand_no = $array[1];

Answer (score 1):

Try using either file_get_contents("php://input") or HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA in your postjson.php file

Answer (score 0):

Are you returning the $result variable somewhere?

Comment: My reputation does not qualify me to help via a comment. ;)

Comment: I have printed $result in the posted.php and it's showing the array posted ,but i want to print them in postjson.php page,where the data is getting posted.